# are questions about open records requests valid?

Tags: discussion

So I did an open records request to the state of TX and was wanting to get some feedback from it. Would this be an appropriate venue?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'get feedback' ?

Comment: Are you trying to find the data released elsewhere or are you needing help with the Texas process?

Comment: Need help with the process.

Answer (score 1):

We have a number of process questions for open record requests already. Go for it.